# tf.fromPixels from video element is super slow on safari

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

this.video.current! is a reference to an html video element.
let tensor = tf.fromPixels(this.video.current!);  T

When I run this line on safari, the video stream starts to freeze. The line itself executes pretty quickly but the frames seems to freeze and I keep getting repetitive values for the video element. When I get rid of this line, I seem to be getting new values from the video stream. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: When do you call this?

Comment: I have a recursive function that just has this line and then calls the function again in a requestanimation frame. Removing that line means the video cam feed looks fine. I can also see that this specific line is not stalling anything  logs after it get printed.

Comment: And you didn't forget to not use () on the function when passing it to request animation frame? Please provide more code.